# Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent in Plunker

Tags: angular

This is a minimal example: http://plnkr.co/edit/p0ORaBt2JGV0QlC5YBLw?p=preview

I set the `Providers` and `@Injectable`, but it still complains about `Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent`

Could someone have a look and kindly tell me why? I checked some similar existing posts and the solutions to them don't seem to work . (E.g. add `@inject`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `app.components.ts` as below :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  do() {
      let a = this.http.get('abc').subscribe();    
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Angular</h1>'
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: AService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('abc');
    this.service.do();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize the order matters